# How to find a template function via detours?

Tags: c++, function, templates, detours

I want to mod an existing, already compiled and statically linked program via detours. Especially by using "DetourFindFunction" to find a specific template function pointer.

I've got the .pdb available and found the function I want with the correct template with IDA. But how can I find its function pointer via Microsoft Detours?

I tried already stuff like:

```
DetourFindFunction("My.exe", "FunctionName<std::string>");
```

It should search and find the corresponding template function and give me the function pointer, but I only get a nullptr.

Comment: Did you try the things listed here? https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/DetourFindFunction

Comment: FWIW Templates don't exist in compiled code.  `template <typename T> void foo(T){}` just becomes `void foo(int) {}` after the compiler stamps it out for an `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not really correct, at least in terms of name mangling (which should be what matters): https://godbolt.org/z/4HZqDJ - `_Z3bari` vs `_Z3fooIiEvT_`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof sry, but I already searched for the template stuff on that page but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It seems that you have wrong assumptions about detours capabilities. Template functions are often inlined and / or interleaved with other code so unless this function is being specifically exported there could simply be no function to get a pointer to.

Comment: @VTT but why have found the function IDA and is there another way to do that?

Comment: I think it is just information from .pdb on which part of the source code corresponds to which part of compiled code. This does not mean that that template function has been compiled into a separate function so you can get a pointer to it.

Comment: @VTT ok, but is there any other way in doing this?